# returning array from class method

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Currently I am having a few issues returning an array from a class' method. here is my little test:

Here is my method:

```
private function getUser($uid,$set,$params){
        switch($set){
            case 'dvar':
                $col = $params[0];
                $needle = $params[1];

                $res = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT col,val FROM acl_users_dvars WHERE uid=:uid");
                $res->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
                $res->execute();
                foreach($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k=>$v){
                    $rows[$k]=$v;
                }
                return($rows);
            break;
        }

    }
```

now, `vardump`ing directly above `return $rows;` results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [col] => thisiscol!
            [val] => this...is.my.VARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [col] => thisiscol2!
            [val] => this is my bar
        )

)
```

However, on the page I initialize the class and call the method:

```
$user = array(
    '5',
    'dvar',
    array('thisiscol!')
);
$tOb = $test->getResponce('get_user',$user);
var_dump($tOb);
```

I am simply returned with:

```
NULL
```

**edit**

as stated from the last answer, and i am sorry I completely left this out: Here is a partial from my getResponce method:

```
public function getResponce($do_what, $parameters){
        switch(strtolower($do_what)){
                case 'create_user':
                    self::createUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1]);
                break;
                case 'remove_user':
                    self::remUser($parameters[0]);
                break;
                case 'set_user':
                    self::setUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1],$parameters[2]);
                break;
                case 'get_user':
                    self::getUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1],$parameters[2]);
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function name says `getUser()` but you are attempting to call `getResponce()` -

```
$user = array(
    '5',
    'dvar',
    array('thisiscol!')
);
$tOb = $test->getResponce('get_user',$user);
var_dump($tOb);
```

I think you got the answer :)

**UPDATE**
In your calling params array, you are just keeping `array('thisiscol!')`

```
$user = array(
    '5',
    'dvar',
    array('thisiscol!')
);
```

But inside the `getUser()` function, you are trying to access

```
            $col = $params[0];
            $needle = $params[1];
```

I see `$params[1]` is missing.

**ALSO**

Try adding `return` in your `getResponce()`

Answer (score 1):

Your "getResponce" doesn't forward the return value of the "getUser" method.

```
public function getResponce($do_what, $parameters){
        switch(strtolower($do_what)){
                case 'create_user':
                    return self::createUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1]);
                break;
                case 'remove_user':
                    return self::remUser($parameters[0]);
                break;
                case 'set_user':
                    return self::setUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1],$parameters[2]);
                break;
                case 'get_user':
                    return self::getUser($parameters[0],$parameters[1],$parameters[2]);
                break;
```

Comment: there it was. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

For a better overview i would also recommend to declare $row before your loop.

```
$res->execute();
$rows = array();
foreach($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $k=>$v){
  $rows[$k]=$v;
}
return($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only one line like this : `$rows = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

```
 private function getUser($uid,$set,$params){
      switch($set){
          case 'dvar':
            $col = $params[0];
            $needle = $params[1];

            $res = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT col,val FROM acl_users_dvars WHERE uid=:uid");
            $res->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
            $res->execute();
            $rows = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
            return $rows;
        break;
     }

 }
```

Comment: this also returns a `null` value however I did not know this, thank you!